# How do I move the strike plate on my bedroom door down by 1 cm?

Tags: doors, screws

My bedroom door in my apartment won't stay shut. It seems the strike plate is about 1 cm too high. I will need to lower it. If I lower it, I will need to drill 2 new holes. I think if I do so, the holes will be too close together and they might become one hole when I put the screws in the new holes.

Am I wrong about this? Is there a solution I can use?

Comment: 1/2" off is HUGE and there is no way a competent human installer would install it so far off.  May be proof of aliens.   OR, there's another problem that caused the door to move after installation, like a hinge coming loose.

Comment: Maybe I over estimated. I will get my tape measure and see.

Comment: Another possibility is the house itself distorting, perhaps with ground subsidence or moisture change. Is the door square to its frame? Check the top edge of the door against the door frame.

Comment: @Harper, after lowering it, I measure how much I brought it down. It measured out to be 1cm. So it was a little short of 1/2 an inch. I did over estimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used wood filler and match sticks to plug up the old holes. I used a chisel to widen the bolt hole on the bottom as well as carve out an indentation for the plate. Drilled in 2 new holes and put the plate on using the old screws.

The door can finally close properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the existing strike, then use Bondo, JB Weld, or epoxy putty to fill all the existing holes before reinstalling the strike. This will give the screws something to bite into and prevent wood splitting. You would reinstall as if you were doing a totally new installation.